# Checkout a repository is not working, how to fix that?

Tags: powershell, github, github-actions

This is the error I got if I tried to use the default directory for cloning three separate repositories.

I had three repositories which need to be there for the build process, so I used the checkout action and tried below workflow, but not working.

I tried with and without sub directories but same issue, and even with ref also but same issue. No response in github community also

> ````
> [25](https://github.com/company-inc/company-main-MCL/runs/6722491941?check_suite_focus=true#step:2:25)
> with:
>
> [26](https://github.com/company-inc/company-main-MCL/runs/6722491941?check_suite_focus=true#step:2:26)
> repository: company-inc/company_BookShelf_and_MITI
>
> [27](https://github.com/company-inc/company-main-MCL/runs/6722491941?check_suite_focus=true#step:2:27)
> token: ***
>
> [28](https://github.com/company-inc/company-main-MCL/runs/6722491941?check_suite_focus=true#step:2:28)
> path: bkslf
>
> [29](https://github.com/company-inc/company-main-MCL/runs/6722491941?check_suite_focus=true#step:2:29)
> ssh-strict: true
>
> [30](https://github.com/company-inc/company-main-MCL/runs/6722491941?check_suite_focus=true#step:2:30)
> persist-credentials: true
>
> [31](https://github.com/company-inc/company-main-MCL/runs/6722491941?check_suite_focus=true#step:2:31)
> clean: true
>
> [32](https://github.com/company-inc/company-main-MCL/runs/6722491941?check_suite_focus=true#step:2:32)
> fetch-depth: 1
>
> [33](https://github.com/company-inc/company-main-MCL/runs/6722491941?check_suite_focus=true#step:2:33)
> lfs: false
>
> [34](https://github.com/company-inc/company-main-MCL/runs/6722491941?check_suite_focus=true#step:2:34)
> submodules: false
>
> [35](https://github.com/company-inc/company-main-MCL/runs/6722491941?check_suite_focus=true#step:2:35)
> set-safe-directory: true
>
> [36](https://github.com/company-inc/company-main-MCL/runs/6722491941?check_suite_focus=true#step:2:37)Syncing
> repository: company-inc/company_BookShelf_and_MITI
>
> [14](https://github.com/company-inc/company-main-MCL/runs/6722491941?check_suite_focus=true#step:2:15)Getting
> Git version info
>
> [16](https://github.com/company-inc/company-main-MCL/runs/6722491941?check_suite_focus=true#step:2:18)The
> repository will be downloaded using the GitHub REST API
>
> [17](https://github.com/company-inc/company-main-MCL/runs/6722491941?check_suite_focus=true#step:2:19)To
> create a local Git repository instead, add Git 2.18 or higher to the
> PATH
>
> [18](https://github.com/company-inc/company-main-MCL/runs/6722491941?check_suite_focus=true#step:2:20)Determining the default branch
>
> [19](https://github.com/company-inc/company-main-MCL/runs/6722491941?check_suite_focus=true#step:2:21)Retrieving
> the default branch name
>
> [20](https://github.com/company-inc/company-main-MCL/runs/6722491941?check_suite_focus=true#step:2:22)Default
> branch 'master'
>
> [21](https://github.com/company-inc/company-main-MCL/runs/6722491941?check_suite_focus=true#step:2:23)Downloading the archive
>
> [22](https://github.com/company-inc/company-main-MCL/runs/6722491941?check_suite_focus=true#step:2:24)Writing
> archive to disk
>
> [23](https://github.com/company-inc/company-main-MCL/runs/6722491941?check_suite_focus=true#step:2:25)Extracting
> the archive
>
> [24](https://github.com/company-inc/company-main-MCL/runs/6722491941?check_suite_focus=true#step:2:26)C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
> -NoLogo -Sta -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop' ; try { Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem } catch { } ; [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory('C:\actions-runner\_work\company-main-MCL\company-main-MCL\bkslf\5e4f39ba-0d1a-479e-8c42-e6e9952567a9.tar.gz',
> 'C:\actions-runner\_work\company-main-MCL\company-main-MCL\bkslf\5e4f39ba-0d1a-479e-8c42-e6e9952567a9')"
>
> [25](https://github.com/company-inc/company-main-MCL/runs/6722491941?check_suite_focus=true#step:2:27)Exception
> calling "ExtractToDirectory" with "2" argument(s): "Could not find a
> part of the path 'C:\actions-runner\_wor
>
> [26](https://github.com/company-inc/company-main-MCL/runs/6722491941?check_suite_focus=true#step:2:28)k\company-main-MCL\company-main-MCL\bkslf\5e4f39ba-0d1a-479e-8c42-e6e9952567a9\company-inc-company_BookShelf_and_MITI-babde4ccd
>
> [27](https://github.com/company-inc/company-main-MCL/runs/6722491941?check_suite_focus=true#step:2:29)b077a79de53ad1d5cb54c7e1dcc2c29\12.1\Content\Installation\Implementation\(Optional)
> Apply a Theme to Individual
>
> [28](https://github.com/company-inc/company-main-MCL/runs/6722491941?check_suite_focus=true#step:2:30)Objects
> in a Model.html'."
>
> [29](https://github.com/company-inc/company-main-MCL/runs/6722491941?check_suite_focus=true#step:2:31)At
> line:1 char:111
>
> [30](https://github.com/company-inc/company-main-MCL/runs/6722491941?check_suite_focus=true#step:2:32)+
> ... catch { } ;
> [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory('C:\a ...
>
> [31](https://github.com/company-inc/company-main-MCL/runs/6722491941?check_suite_focus=true#step:2:33)+
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> [32](https://github.com/company-inc/company-main-MCL/runs/6722491941?check_suite_focus=true#step:2:34)
> + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>
> [33](https://github.com/company-inc/company-main-MCL/runs/6722491941?check_suite_focus=true#step:2:35)
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirectoryNotFoundException
>
> [34](https://github.com/company-inc/company-main-MCL/runs/6722491941?check_suite_focus=true#step:2:36)
>
> [35](https://github.com/company-inc/company-main-MCL/runs/6722491941?check_suite_focus=true#step:2:37)Error:
> The process
> 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe' failed
> with exit code 1 ```
> ````

My workflow:

```
# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions

name: CIDependencies

# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the master branch
  push:
    branches: [ r12.1_githubactions ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ r12.1_githubactions ]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:



# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  DownloadDependencies:
    runs-on: DevBuild2
    steps:
      - name: bookshelf
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          repository: company-inc/company_BookShelf_and_MITI
          token: ${{ secrets.DM_TOKEN }}
          path: bkslf
      - name: DMDependencies
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          repository: company-inc/company_DM_Dependencies
          token: ${{ secrets.DM_TOKEN }} 
          path: dep
      - name: installs_repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          repository: company-inc/company-Installshield
          token: ${{ secrets.DM_TOKEN }}
          path: ins
```

New pipeline/workflow.

```
# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions

name: CIDependencies

# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the master branch
  push:
    branches: [ r12.1_githubactions ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ r12.1_githubactions ]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:



# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  DownloadDependencies:
    runs-on: DevBuild2
    steps:
      - name: bookshelf
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          repository: company-inc/company_BookShelf_and_MITI
          token: ${{ secrets.DM_TOKEN }}
```

And the error I got.

```
Run actions/checkout@v3
  with:
    repository: company-inc/company_BookShelf_and_MITI
    token: ***
    ssh-strict: true
    persist-credentials: true
    clean: true
    fetch-depth: 1
    lfs: false
    submodules: false
    set-safe-directory: true
Syncing repository: company-inc/company_BookShelf_and_MITI
Getting Git version info
  Working directory is 'C:\actions-runner\_work\company-main-MCL\company-main-MCL'
Deleting the contents of 'C:\actions-runner\_work\company-main-MCL\company-main-MCL'
The repository will be downloaded using the GitHub REST API
To create a local Git repository instead, add Git 2.18 or higher to the PATH
Determining the default branch
Retrieving the default branch name
Default branch 'master'
Downloading the archive
Writing archive to disk
Extracting the archive
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -Sta -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop' ; try { Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem } catch { } ; [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory('C:\actions-runner\_work\company-main-MCL\company-main-MCL\93e33dc4-929d-4ef3-9ae1-542c863de582.tar.gz', 'C:\actions-runner\_work\company-main-MCL\company-main-MCL\93e33dc4-929d-4ef3-9ae1-542c863de582')"
Exception calling "ExtractToDirectory" with "2" argument(s): "Could not find a part of the path 'C:\actions-runner\_wor
k\company-main-MCL\company-main-MCL\93e33dc4-929d-4ef3-9ae1-542c863de582\company-inc-company_BookShelf_and_MITI-babde4ccdb077a7
9de53ad1d5cb54c7e1dcc2c29\12.1\Content\Installation\Implementation\(Optional) Apply a Theme to Individual Objects in a 
Model.html'."
At line:1 char:111
+ ... catch { } ; [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory('C:\a ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirectoryNotFoundException
Error: The process 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe' failed with exit code 1
Run actions/checkout@v3
  with:
    repository: company-inc/company_BookShelf_and_MITI
    token: ***
    ssh-strict: true
    persist-credentials: true
    clean: true
    fetch-depth: 1
    lfs: false
    submodules: false
    set-safe-directory: true
Syncing repository: company-inc/company_BookShelf_and_MITI
Getting Git version info
  Working directory is 'C:\actions-runner\_work\company-main-MCL\company-main-MCL'
Deleting the contents of 'C:\actions-runner\_work\company-main-MCL\company-main-MCL'
The repository will be downloaded using the GitHub REST API
To create a local Git repository instead, add Git 2.18 or higher to the PATH
Determining the default branch
Retrieving the default branch name
Default branch 'master'
Downloading the archive
Writing archive to disk
Extracting the archive
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -Sta -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop' ; try { Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem } catch { } ; [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory('C:\actions-runner\_work\company-main-MCL\company-main-MCL\93e33dc4-929d-4ef3-9ae1-542c863de582.tar.gz', 'C:\actions-runner\_work\company-main-MCL\company-main-MCL\93e33dc4-929d-4ef3-9ae1-542c863de582')"
Exception calling "ExtractToDirectory" with "2" argument(s): "Could not find a part of the path 'C:\actions-runner\_wor
k\company-main-MCL\company-main-MCL\93e33dc4-929d-4ef3-9ae1-542c863de582\company-inc-company_BookShelf_and_MITI-babde4ccdb077a7
9de53ad1d5cb54c7e1dcc2c29\12.1\Content\Installation\Implementation\(Optional) Apply a Theme to Individual Objects in a 
Model.html'."
At line:1 char:111
+ ... catch { } ; [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory('C:\a ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirectoryNotFoundException
Error: The process 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe' failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Could you please try and remove all unrelated clutter? E.g. do you get the same error with only one checkout? Then please remove the other two. Please also cleanup the logs. There's an error about `DirectoryNotFoundException`. Perhaps that's a problem?

Comment: Why DIrectoryNotFound coming in cloning a repo?
What files do you want me to check on an empty machine, where no code downloaded yet?

Comment: Added details with only one repo, can you cehck once